# Why UIScrolIView is not scrolling with .xib file objects?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I tried a lot to scroll `UIScrollView` with .xib file objects like `UIButton` etc, but it is not scrolling with these objects. Whenever I made buttons programmatically and added in scrollview, it scrolls fine. I didn't understand this problem. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

If your scrollView's `contentSize` isn't big enough(exceed your scrollView's size) or you haven't set `alwaysBounceVertical`(`alwaysBounceHorizontal`) to `YES`, a single button in a scrollView cannot be scrolled.

Comment: i know these thing sir, i got 400 by 400 size of scroll view n i got 1600 by 1600 size of its contents with 4 n 5 buttons in it also having a uiview in it but i added these thing from xib objects and these thing totally fulfill the scrolling needs but its not scrolling, n when i added these things programmatically it scrolls fine...

Comment: maybe your content automatically resized. Try checking its size in `-viewWillAppear:`

Answer (score 0):

Without having more information on how you set up the UIScrollView in Interface Builder this is just a guess, but I suspect that you didn't add your UI elements as child views of your UIScrollView, but as siblings.

It should look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: but i think anyone who do programing knows these basic steps! and after all these steps it will not work as well!!!! :)

Comment: you are right. Anyone developing for iOS should know this. Still, sometimes you just miss some of the obvious things. If you want you can share some more details like how you set up your xib and we might be able to find the problem.